# SQL Server can't update with datalayer

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

This is my datalayer query with parameters I want to use

```
public DataTable UpdateUitslag(string Zoek, int thuispunt, int uitpunt)
{
    SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("update TBLUitslag set thuisteampunt = @thuispunt, uitteampunt = @uitpunt where wedstrijdid = @zoeken");

    Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@zoeken", Zoek));  // parameters toevoegen
    Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@thuispunt", Zoek));  // parameters toevoegen
    Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@uitpunt", Zoek));  // parameters toevoegen

    return Database.ExecOverig(Cmd);
}
```

And this is my database execute method:

```
public static bool ExecOverig(SqlCommand Cmd)
{
    bool gelukt = true;

    SqlConnection Connect = new SqlConnection(AllPublic.Conn);
    Cmd.Connection = Connect;

    try
    {
        Cmd.Connection.Open();
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Connect.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        gelukt = false;
    }

    return gelukt;
}

public static bool ExecOverig(string SQL)
{
    return ExecOverig(new SqlCommand(SQL));
}
```

I am getting the error with the following text:

> Cannot implicity convert type 'bool' to System.Data.

Can't figure it out how to do it. I MUST need to use the `ExecOverig()`.

Comment: Your prameter definition is not correct. It should be something like
Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@zoeken", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value=Zoek;
Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@thuispunt", SqlDbType.Int)).Value=thuispunt; 
Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@uitpunt", SqlDbType.Int)).Value=uitpunt;

Comment: You're setting **all** three parameters to the same value, `Zoek` - that can't be what you really want, right??